# Is it possible to wield a weapon similar to Lubbock's?

Tags: akame-ga-kill

In "Akame Ga Kill!",Lubbock is wielding a very complex weapon (a Teigu actually) named Cross Tail,Infinite Possibilities I think...He used it in countless ways,as the name implies,so I was wondering if it would be at least theoretically possible to use such a weapon in an actual fight,with the enemy knowing about your presence and intentions.
I know that such a weapon could only be used for suffocation (stealthily,from the back) or by setting traps,and I'm not very sure about the second one anyway.
Now,I'd like to hear some opinions!

Comment: Erm... Are you asking if one could use a thread-based weapon in ***real life***, or are you asking if Lubbock is capable of wielding his Teigu in an actual (non-stealthy) fight? If it's the latter, Lubbock *did* use his Teigu in actual combat several times, most notably when he confronted and killed 2 Rakshasa Demons single-handedly.

Comment: I'm asking if one could efficiently use a thread-based weapon in real life,sorry if I wasn't clear enough...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Purely theoretical? Yes, you would be able to apply it in real combat. The usage of the weapon would probably be similar to that of a whip or [Kusarigama](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kusarigama). Yet allot harder, due to the lack of weights. This would mean that the user requires the whiplash effect for this weapon to be even have the slightest effect. And this is not even taking armored opponents into account. And in case you were wondering, it would be possible to create such a wire. [WorldBuilding.stackexchange](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/19258) seems to deem it possible.

Realistically speaking, it would be highly unlikely that a weapon such as this would be used in real life combat, as it would require a tremendous amount of skill to effectively use it as a weapon. And most likely wouldn't be feasible against armored opponents.

Finally, with the above said it is save to conclude that the way Lubbock wields the wires would not be realistically possible. With the exception of a few moves.